# Wrong entry vector dimension

Tags: vector

Why my input z must be 2D not 0D if isn't nothing wrong with it. Follows the code if you could help

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

mean_c1 = np.array([0, 0])
cov_c1 = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])

mean_c2 = np.array([4, 4])
cov_c2 = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1])

def bayes_discriminant(x):
    likelihood_c1 = multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean=mean_c1, cov=cov_c1)
    likelihood_c2 = multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean=mean_c2, cov=cov_c2)
    
    discriminant_score = likelihood_c1 - likelihood_c2
    
    return discriminant_score

n_samples = 1000
events_c1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean_c1, cov_c1, n_samples)
events_c2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean_c2, cov_c2, n_samples)

plt.scatter(events_c1[:, 0], events_c1[:, 1], label='Classe C1', alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(events_c2[:, 0], events_c2[:, 1], label='Classe C2', alpha=0.5)

x = np.linspace(-2, 6, 400)
y = np.linspace(-2, 6, 400)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = bayes_discriminant(np.dstack((X, Y)))

plt.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=[0], colors='red')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Distribuição de Classes e Superfície de Separação')
plt.xlabel('Característica 1')
plt.ylabel('Característica 2')
plt.show()
```

The variable z is composed of the variables x and y. However, it seems that the size of the variables x and y is already correct when i unite x with y in Z = bayes_discriminant(np.dstack((X, Y)))